# use regexp to find non-ascii sub string between two single quote

Tags: regex, string

I want to find out if there are substrings between two single quote has non_ascii chars.

Test cases:

```
"abc 'ab中文09中文' 99 '9999' 'abcd' '中文' "
```

Result expected:

```
'ab中文09中文'
'中文'
```

I tried this regexp:

```
/'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+?'/
```

Can get the substring `'中文'` with all non-ascii only. But I also want `'ab中文09中文'` that has non-ascii.

I try to match substring with all ascii chars and reverse the criteria:

```
/'^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?'/
```

But get nothing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you want to match `'ab中文09<>中文'` ?

Comment: No not include double quote in the substring. I'll update my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following regular expression (surrounded `[^']*` to match other ascii/non-ascii characters, and slightly modified the inner character classes not to include `'`):

```
/'[^']*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s'][^']*'/
```

Javascript example:

```
"abc 'ab中文09中文' 99 '9999' 'abcd' '中文' ".match(/'[^']*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s'][^']*'/g)
# => ["'ab中文09中文'", "'中文'"]
```

**UPDATE**

Use following regular expression to match any non-ascii character:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]
```

or

```
[^\000-\177]
```

Comment: Thanks, This approach works great, but in this case `"abc 'ab中文09中文' 99 '9999' 'abcd' /* '中文' " , it will return `'ab中文09中文'` and `' /* '`, the last `'中文'` will be ommited.

Comment: @JaugarChang, `/'[^']*[^\00-\x7f'][^']*'/g` will give you what you want.

Comment: i think op don't want to match `'><<中文'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I don't understand where does `><<` come from.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, these answers really helps.

Comment: @Jonny5, Ah.. I forgot to update the answer. Thank you for comment.